# Exoplayer/Android Media Player Not Playing Video with AC3 Audio

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer version 2 for playing Video from Internal Storage and it works fine but whenever video contains ac3 type audio,exoplayer not plays audio,it only display video.
please help me

```
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeter);
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory().setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true);
videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
player.prepare(videoSource);
```

Same Problem also Occurring with Android Media player

Comment: you need to use extention to decode that format check out this link https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1750#issuecomment-240394868

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. i'll have a look at it!

Comment: Thank you bro..i'm very near to solve my problem using your provided link

Comment: thats great , if you solve that then post detail answer here, have a look for refrance https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html#ffmpeg-extension